# Can you automatically generate an acronym list as a table in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, acronym

What is the easiest way to create an acronyms list as a table that may be automatically generated, such as a table of contents?  I'm assuming acronyms are 3 letters or greater.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you after

- a **glossary**: alphabetically sorted list of acronyms with respective explanations, or
- an **index**: alphabetically sorted list of terms which may be acronyms or not, which also includes the page number where the term is introduced/explained?

You can create an index which can be then updated like ToC. To do so you need *(assuming Word 2010)*:

1. Mark items/terms which are to be included in the index:

   - highlight the term in text
   - move to the **Reference** tab of the ribbon
   - click **Mark Entry** in the index section
   - alter the entry if you need to (e.g. you highlighted `Stack Exchange` but you want the index entry to say `Stack Exchange (SE)` - you can do that in the **Main entry** text box)
   - do the above for all terms you want to include
2. Insert the index where appropriate:

   - when ready click **Insert index** (Reference tab of the ribbon again) while being in the appropriate place in the document
   - you can later **Update index** after marking more terms

Hope this helps.

Comment: Word 2010 or later. It works for modern 365 Word.

Answer (score 2):

From your question, I believe there could be 2 possible scenarios:

- Document is scanned for suitable abbreviations (e.g. all CAP, min 3 letters), then generate a table listing them. You could then manually add their definitions in one turn.
- Define each abbreviation along the way as you use them in the document, then let Word auto generate the table, listing them with their defined meaning.

Scenario 1: I don’t really know any reliable method. There are all kinds of abbreviation, short/long, capitalized/not capitalized, with/without dot, etc. My point is, I don’t trust that, any algorithm can detect all those forms. 
So no idea here, but if you decide to go with…

Scenario 2: **Index table**

Originally, index table is used to list out keywords, to keep track where they appear in the document, and not for abbreviations, so there are supposed to be disadvantages here – more on that later.

So as I mentioned, let’s say you are writing the document, then you use the abbreviation ‘etc’. You can do as followed:

- Highlight **etc**
- Go to **References** on the ribbon, and **Mark Entry** (or **Shift + Alt + X**)
- In Mark Index Entry window, check **Cross-reference**, delete the preset word *See*, and type ‘et cetera’
- Press **Mark**, you can close the window.

Continue with your document, and with other abbreviations.

You would notice that Word’s code markings for the index show up inline. These would not be there when you print out the document (unless you specifically choose to print markings) so just ignore them; **OR** if you are such a format fanatic like me and have to get rid of them, just to Home on the ribbon and click on the paragraph icon ¶. You might also have to delve into Word’s **Options** / **Display** and uncheck **Hidden text**.

Eventually you want to create the table: Go to **References** again, and **Insert Index**. A window pops up; this is what you need:

- Check **Right align page numbers**
- Tab leader: **(none)**
- Formats: **From template**
- Columns: **1**
- Click on **Modify**
- Modify the **Index 1**

I would suggest you modify **Paragraph** and **Tabs** from the **Format** button on the bottom left of the window.

Let’s set **Paragraph**, **Left Indent** to 3 cm; for **Tabs**, type 7 cm and **Set**, remember to check **Leader: none**.

OK and confirm all settings and you should have the table in place.

**Pros** and **Cons**: Like everything else, there are always 2 sides.

This method gives you the automatic table of abbreviations, in alphabetical order. Problem is, the definition of those abbreviations cannot be made non-italic, due to the format of the system. You will have to *manually* turn off italic afterward.

You can also not separate the format of abbreviations and their definitions, since they belong to the same class.

But at least it works and we have a decent result. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

There are online services such as [acromatic.uk](http://acromatic.uk) that will collate a list of the acronyms that you've used in your Word document, for you to add back into your document.

For [that site](http://acromatic.uk), you would go through the following process:

1. Choose how you want to define an acronym (e.g. minimum length, can it contain numbers)
2. Upload your Word document
3. You'll be given a sorted list of the acronyms used that can be pasted back into your report.  *You will have to provide definitions yourself.*

There are advantages and disadvantages to this route, compared to adapting features that are native to Word (see other answers for these).

**Benefits:**

1. It is much harder to miss out any acronyms, because you don't have to mark them yourself in the text -- the site will find everything.
2. You don't have to do anything while you are writing the document, only at the end (which may be good if other people are contributing to a report).

**Downsides**:

1. You have to define every acronym yourself *at the end*.  This may cause various problems, not least that you can't add to your document, click a button and regenerate an updated acronym list automatically.
2. The site may well pick up strings of letters that you don't intend as acronyms, which you'll have to delete.
3. As with any service on the internet, consider the security implications of uploading anything sensitive.

Full disclosure: I wrote acromatic.uk (and have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)).

Answer (score 0):

****If you have an Enterprise Office 365 subscription,**** Word has a feature to find and see a list of acronyms (source: [microsoft support website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/find-acronym-definitions-89062352-e1ce-4f59-b58c-f94869521404)).

> To see a list of defined acronyms,
>
> 1. Go to **References** > **Acronyms**.
> 2. In the **Acronyms** pane, find the acronyms from your document with their definitions.

---

**Otherwise** then I believe the "easiest way" (at least compared to the other answers) is this online tool: https://listofacronyms.com

It finds acronyms broadly so there will likely be more than the ones you want but the cost of deleting a false positive (one click on a cross) feels justified compared to the impact of potentially missing acronyms.

It will also attempt to fill your list with each acronym's definition provided you wrote it down the first time you used the acronym, like so:

> A central processing unit (CPU) is...

Disclosure: I created this tool.